# How do I use the Django for template tag in Dojo?

Tags: django, django-templates, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to use the "for" Django template tag in my javascript. Iam using Dojo's DataGrid to create a list of items. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['dojox/grid/DataGrid' , 'dojo/data/ItemFileWriteStore' , 'dojo/dom' , 'dojo/domReady!'],
      function(DataGrid, ItemFileWriteStore, dom){
        /*set up data store*/
        var data = {
          identifier: "id",
          items: []
        };

        {% for item in items_list %}
            data.items.push({ id: {{ item.url }} + '_' + {{ item.id }}, col1: {{ item.description }} });
        {% endfor %}

        var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

        /*set up layout*/
        var layout = [[
            {'name': 'Description', 'field': 'id', 'width': '100px'}
        ]];

        /*create a new grid*/
        var grid = new DataGrid({
            id: 'grid',
            store: store,
            structure: layout,
            rowSelector: '20px'
        }, "grid");

        /*Call startup() to render the grid*/
        grid.startup();
    });
</script>
```

However, when I go to my webpage, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add quotes around the values in the dictionary

```
data.items.push({ id: '{{ item.url }}_{{ item.id }}', col1: '{{ item.description }}' });
```